# Convert date with no hyphens or spaces to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

for school I need to make an application with the RDW API. (RDW is a Dutch government instance that registers all the cars).

A part of the response I'm getting back looks like this:

```
[
        "vervaldatum_apk": "20210402",
        "datum_tenaamstelling": "20100318",
]
```

These numbers are dates without hyphens or spaces.
How do I convert them to JavaScript dates?
I've tried to use the moment.js module but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Is `20210402` supposed to translate to the date 2021, the 2nd of April? Also is your array `[]` supposed to be an object `{}`?

Comment: With moment.js you'd use `moment(vervaldatum_apk, 'YYYYMMDD')`, but POJS is simple too. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the entries of your object, where you take the value `v` from each entry and use a regular expression to format it in the form of a date string. Here the expression used is:

```
/(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})/g
```

This will take the first *n-4* digits of your number and group it into group #1. This group is later referenced using `$1` in the replace. It will then take the next 2 digits representing the month, and group those into group #2 (referenced using `$2`). Lastly, it will take the remaining two digits and group it into group #3. You can then replace the matched components so they contain a `-` between each group. You can then wrap this in a `new Date()` constructor to get your JavaScript date object. 
Once you've mapped all the entries in the entires array, you can convert it back into an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const obj = {"vervaldatum_apk": "20210402", "datum_tenaamstelling": "20100318"};
const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, new Date(v.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3'))])
);
console.log(res);
```

If you can't support `Object.fromEntries()`, you can use an alternative method. One way would be to use `Object.assign()` with the spread syntax:

```js
const obj = {"vervaldatum_apk": "20210402", "datum_tenaamstelling": "20100318"};
const res = Object.assign({},
  ...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: new Date(v.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3'))}))
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That will parse the date as UTC, not local, which might be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using a regular expression to match each date group and then recreate the date using a template string.

```js
const getDate = (date) => {
    const {year, month, day} = date.match(/(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})/, 'ig').groups;

    return new Date(`${year}.${month}.${day}`);
}
```

The regex string above uses [named capture groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups), the returning object from the match operation will contain a group object that contains the *year*, *month* and *day*

Then you create a `.` separated date below using a template string.

Answer (score 1):

(I think @Einar Ólafsson already provided a clearer or shorter version)
 @Puk,I am not sure if I understand the question well enough, but assuming this is Javascript object especially the `"20210402"` and the `"20100318"`  I would do something like this:

```
//starting with 
    [
        "vervaldatum_apk":"20210402",
        "datum_tenaamstelling":"20100318"
    ]
    // convert to date
   const vervaldatum = new Date(parseInt("20210402"))
   const datum = new Date(parseInt("20100318"))

    // Format each of them
    // Germany uses day-month-year format

    // formatting vervaldatum_apk
  const formatted_vervaldatum_apk  = `${vervaldatum.getDay()}-${vervaldatum.getMonth()}-${vervaldatum.getDay()}-${vervaldatum.getFullYear()}, ${vervaldatum.getHours()}:${vervaldatum.getMinutes()}:${vervaldatum.getSeconds()}`

    // formatting datum_tenaamstelling
  const formatted_datum_tenaamstelling = `${datum.getDay()}-${datum.getMonth()}-${datum.getFullYear()}, ${datum.getHours()}:${datum.getMinutes()}:${datum.getSeconds()}`

    // Formatted  object
  const formattedDateObject = {
    vervaldatum_apk: formatted_vervaldatum_apk ,
    datum_tenaamstelling: formatted_datum_tenaamstelling
  }

  /// this is the object 
  formattedDateObject = {
    datum_tenaamstelling: "3-11-1969, 22:35:0",
    vervaldatum_apk: "3-11-3-1969, 22:36:50"
  }
  // Formatted array
     // So from 
     [
        "vervaldatum_apk":"20210402",
        "datum_tenaamstelling":"20100318"
    ]
    // you end up with (hour, minutes, and seconds added)
  [
      "vervaldatum_apk":"3-11-3-1969, 22:36:50",
      "datum_tenaamstelling":"3-11-1969, 22:35:0"
  ]
```